# Accessing the Windows Recycle Bin in WSL2

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, recycle-bin

In WSL2, is it possible to access the Windows Recycling Bin? Say for example you move `file.txt` into the recycling bin in the Windows GUI, could you move to the directory that `file.txt` is contained in on the WSL terminal? How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Officially, no. A special implementation of `IShellFolder` in shell32 handles the recycle bin when files are moved/deleted in the shell namespace.

Unofficially, each drive contains a hidden $Recycle.Bin folder (Recycler before Vista). Each user has a directory inside there named after their SID where their deleted files are stored.

The deleted files do not retain their original filenames, only their extension. Before Vista, a file named INFO2 stored this information. These days $I... stores the information for the original files renamed to $R...

Look at forensics tools like [Rifiuti2](https://abelcheung.github.io/rifiuti2/) if you need to understand the internal format so you can extract the original name...